# How to check if a string contains only letters in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I want to write a PHP code which checks whether a variable contains only letters NOT characters not numbers, I have typed this but it's not working:

```
$myVar = "Var#iable5";

ereg(^[a-zA-Z] , $myVar)
```

Comment: Sidenote: [`ereg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) is deprecated. *"This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged."*

Comment: Could you define "letter" as opposed to "character"? Is é a letter? Is ∑?

Comment: @mattgibson -- or what about good old ß?

Comment: Letter is A , B , C ....     
Characters # , ! , "" , ^

Comment: I can't tell from your response whether é, ß, ∑, etc.—perfectly normal, extremely common letters in a variety of languages, just like A B or C—should count or not. Perhaps you could tell us why you want to do this? It might help us to understand the requirements better.

Answer (score 14):

No need for regex:

```
$result = ctype_alpha($myVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by not using ereg(). That's been deprecrated for literally years, and WILL be removed from PHP at some point. Plus, your pattern is incorrect. `^` as you're using it is a pattern anchor, signifying "start of line".

You want:

```
preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]/', $myVar)
```

instead. As the first char inside a `[]` group, `^` means "Not", so "NOT a-zA-Z", not "[a-zA-Z] at start of line" as you were trying.

Comment: The function you typed in is returning TRUE. It shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in function to do that: [`ctype_alpha`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)

```
$myVar = "Var#iable5"; 
var_dump (ctype_alpha($myVar)); // false
```

From the docs:

> Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are alphabetic. In the standard C locale letters are just [A-Za-z] and ctype_alpha() is equivalent to (ctype_upper($text) || ctype_lower($text)) if $text is just a single character, but other languages have letters that are considered neither upper nor lower case.